# How to check the parent window

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am having a problem getting to the parent window.
I have a window that has 2 frames... one of the frame opens another window which in returns open a third window. In the third window I want to refresh the very first window by doing this

```
window.opener.window.opener.close();
```

it only works for non frame setup...what can I use for the frame. I am open to using jQuery too.

Answer (score 1):

Calle's answer looks like a good suggestion. In my experiments IE and Firefox would let me go 2 back to the parent iframe to access functions, but Chrome gave me a security violation.